# Use different «Single.php» for custom categories

Tags: single

I want to make two **single.php**, The first **single.php** display all **categories** content but not display two **categories**, and I want to make a different **single.php** for that two categories, I hope to help me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
 if ( in_category('cat1') || in_category('cat2')) {
        include 'single-cattwo.php'; //for the 2 categories
    } else {
        // Default
        include 'single-allcat.php';//all categories
    }
```

inside `single.php`